# Cell Queue Size in UITable View

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uitableview

I used **dequeueReusableCell()** to control the cell in **UITableView** , and to know how this will work I read **[this](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableview/1614878-dequeuereusablecell)** documentation from **Apple**.

This article explains what this method does and how you can deal with it.

But I wanna to know how it determines the size of ReusableCellQueue.

I knew that this method determines a specific size of the queue that data source has marked for reuse. And there is a range of cell in the queue to simplify the displaying data from queue to user.

The second question, when I scroll down, does the above cell delete from Queue?

If it does, when I return back to above, will this cells recreated?

Answer (score 2):

Reusable queue is determined by internal algorithm. Most of it is associated by a screen size and how many cells are presented on the screen. Once cell become visible, it will reuse view of previous one that is out of bounds of the screen.

Comment: Thanks for replay :), but can I know the size of the queue?

Comment: and if you know if cells remove from this queue if i scroll down ?

Comment: No one can guarantee size of the queue, but let's say cells visible on the screen + 4. Invisible cells are "destroyed" and will be reused once they show again.